# How can I plot a stars in color?

Tags: r, plot

I have a 5x7 matrix I want to plot as a radar or spider chart?  For example:

```
stars(mtcars[, 1:7], locations = c(0,0), radius = FALSE,
      key.loc=c(0,0), main="Motor Trend Cars", lty = 2)
```

[image: stars plot]

I'd like each of these lines to be a different color (and/or different style) so I can make out what I'm looking at.

Comment: I didn't know this method, bu the help for it states parameters `col.segments` and `col.stars`. Don't these do the trick?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  They seem to fill in the whole thing.  col.stars lets me do this:  https://skitch.com/dlsspy/fq6ga/col.stars and col.segments lets me do this:  https://skitch.com/dlsspy/fq6g5/segments

Comment: Maybe you should add an example of what you'd like to see (created manually, perhaps with a smaller dataset). It is not obvious (to me) which lines you wish to see in different colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following suggestion is a bit of a hack. I'm sure a more elegant solution is possible.

1. Get the function source of `stars`, and make a copy: let's call it `stars2`
2. Add an extra argument in the `stars2` argument list: `col.lines = NULL`
3. Change the following of code from: `polygon(s.x[i, ], s.y[i, ], lwd = lwd, lty = lty, col = col.stars[i])` to `polygon(s.x[i, ], s.y[i, ], lwd = lwd, lty = lty, border = col.lines[i], col = col.stars[i])`
4. Call `stars2` providing a color for each of your stars.

The sample call and output (left = before, right = after) are below.

```
stars2(mtcars[, 1:7], locations = c(0,0), radius = FALSE,key.loc=c(0,0), 
       main="Motor Trend Cars", lty = 2,col.lines = 1:nrow(mtcars))
```

[image]

Comment: 5. Find the creator of stars and email him this as an extension suggestion

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for, but it does seem to be the answer.  I'll try to contribute this change back to the R project, preferably attributed to you.

Comment: and he did, ... and I now have added the new feature to 'R-devel' (the development version of R which will become R 2.14.0 in October.

Comment: Cool! Great to hear :-) In general, making edited versions of functions is certainly faster than getting things changed in base R or the relevant package version.